# Initialize array of integer

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I have problem about inialize of integer.

```
package mytypes is
    type gamma_cor_array is array (NATURAL RANGE <>) of integer range 15 downto 0;
end mytypes;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
use work.mytypes.all;

entity gamma_correction is
    GENERIC (DEPH : natural:=4; GAMMA_COR : real:=1.0);
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
        gamma_cor_array_s : out gamma_cor_array(2**DEPH-1 downto 0):= (others => 0));

end gamma_correction;

architecture Behavioral of gamma_correction is

begin
    PROCESS (clk) BEGIN
        IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
            for i in 0 to (2**DEPH - 1) loop
                gamma_cor_array_s(i) <= integer(((real(i)/real(2**DEPH - 1))**GAMMA_COR)*real(2**DEPH - 1));
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I get these warnings:

> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:1>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:2>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:2>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:2>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <3:3>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:3>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .
>
> WARNING:Xst:2404 -  FFs/Latches <1:4>> (without
>   init value) have a constant value of 0 in block .

In testbench my code is working ok. Init values are 0, but the warnings still remain. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why isn't gamma_cor_array_s class constant? `GAMMA_COR` is class constant as is `DEPH`, you do not need flip flops, write a function to initialize gamma_cor_s where it is used and don't use an entity/architecture pair.

As is the values of gamma_cor_s are `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)` after rising_edge (clk):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.mytypes.all;  -- type gamma_cor_array

entity gam_cor_tb is
end entity;
architecture foo of gam_cor_tb is
    signal clk: std_logic := '0';
    constant DEPH:  natural := 4;
    constant GAMMA_COR: real := 1.0;
    signal gamma_cor_array_s:  
                gamma_cor_array (2 ** DEPH - 1 downto 0) ;
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;   -- one ping only
    end process;
DUT:
    entity work.gamma_correction
        generic map (
            DEPH => DEPH,
            GAMMA_COR => GAMMA_COR
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            gamma_cor_array_s => gamma_cor_array_s
        );
MONITOR:
    process (gamma_cor_array_s)
    begin
        for i in 0 to (2 ** DEPH - 1) loop
            report "gamma_cor_array_s(" & integer'image(i) & ") = " &
                    integer'image(gamma_cor_array_s(i));
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The results:

> gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(0)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(1) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(2) = 0
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(3)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(4) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(5) = 0
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(6)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(7) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(8) = 0
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(9)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(10) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(11) = 0
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(12)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(13) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(14) = 0
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(15)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(0) = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(1) = 1
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(2)
>   = 2 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(3) = 3 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(4) = 4
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(5)
>   = 5 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(6) = 6 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(7) = 7
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(8)
>   = 8 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(9) = 9 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(10) = 10
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note):
>   gamma_cor_array_s(11) = 11 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(12) = 12
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note):
>   gamma_cor_array_s(13) = 13 gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(14) = 14
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:75:13:@10ns:(report note):
>   gamma_cor_array_s(15) = 15

You declare 64 flip flops, initialize them to all '0' and only 30 of them are changed to '1' - you didn't show all the warnings (which can be ignored here). Use of type real is non-portable (real values are approximate).

The context clause for entity gamma_correction should be:

```
    library ieee; 
    ieee.std_logic_1164.all; -- for type std_logic, function rising_edge
    use ieee.math_real.all;  -- for function "**" [integer, real return real]
    use work.mytypes.all;    -- for type gamma_cor_array
```

The references to unisim are not needed.

For initializing a constant instead of using a signal generated in a separate entity and architecture:

```
architecture fum of gam_cor_tb is
    signal clk: std_logic := '0';
    constant DEPH:  natural := 4;
    constant GAMMA_COR: real := 1.0;
    -- signal gamma_cor_array_s:
    --             gamma_cor_array (2 ** DEPH - 1 downto 0) ;

    function gamma_correct return gamma_cor_array is  -- added pure function
        use ieee.math_real.all;
        variable gamma_cor_array_s: gamma_cor_array(2 ** DEPH - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        for i in 0 to (2 ** DEPH - 1) loop
            gamma_cor_array_s(i) := integer (
                ( (real(i) / real (2 ** DEPH - 1) ) ** GAMMA_COR ) * 
                  real(2 ** DEPH - 1)
            );
        end loop;
        return gamma_cor_array_s;
    end function;

    constant gamma_cor_array_s:  -- previously a signal
                gamma_cor_array (2 ** DEPH - 1 downto 0) := gamma_correct;
begin
-- CLOCK:
--     process
--     begin
--         wait for 10 ns;
--         clk <= not clk;
--         wait for 10 ns;
--         wait;   -- one ping only
--     end process;
-- DUT:
--     entity work.gamma_correction
--         generic map (
--             DEPH => DEPH,
--             GAMMA_COR => GAMMA_COR
--         )
--         port map (
--             clk => clk,
--             gamma_cor_array_s => gamma_cor_array_s
--         );
MONITOR:
    process -- (gamma_cor_array_s)
    begin
        for i in 0 to (2 ** DEPH - 1) loop
            report "gamma_cor_array_s(" & integer'image(i) & ") = " &
                    integer'image(gamma_cor_array_s(i));
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The function specification needs to be within the scope of the the constants previously passed as generic constants to entity gamma_correction.

The function is used to initialize a constant which is a look up table to determine gamma correction.

Notice there is no signal which communicates values between processes based on events. One you assigned gamma_cor_array_s the values were never changed (the driver in the process in entity gamma_correction's architecture).

The output value is:

> gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(0)
>   = 0 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(1) = 1 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(2) = 2
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(3)
>   = 3 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(4) = 4 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(5) = 5
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(6)
>   = 6 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(7) = 7 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(8) = 8
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(9)
>   = 9 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note): gamma_cor_array_s(10) = 10 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(11) = 11
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note):
>   gamma_cor_array_s(12) = 12 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(13) = 13
>   gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report note):
>   gamma_cor_array_s(14) = 14 gamma_corrections.vhdl:126:13:@0ms:(report
>   note): gamma_cor_array_s(15) = 15

which matches the value of the previous signal after the rising edge of clock.

It's possible to make gamma_cor_array_s a signal, subject to dynamic assignment, this requires all assignments are done in one process (a concurrent statement will elaborate a process for an assignment)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You've helped me a lot. I will recommend your site to all my friends...

Comment: A [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can attract good answers.  The result can be more than just a question and an answer. They can be a resource for those with the same or similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Xst reports these warnings because some of the array elements are stuck at zero so that a register is not needed and can be optimized away. To get rid of the warning, you must remove the register description. Or just ignore the warning. Or filter it out in ISE.

The remaining array elements have a constant value after the first clock edge. If you do not care about the initial value (before the first clock edge), then remove the initial value for the array output. Now, the registers can be also removed for these array elements.

If constant values are desired at all time, then no clock is needed. The process can now be reduced to

```
PROCESS BEGIN
    for i in 0 to (2**DEPH - 1) loop
        gamma_cor_array_s(i) <= integer(((real(i)/real(2**DEPH - 1))**GAMMA_COR)*real(2**DEPH - 1));
    end loop;
    wait;
end process;
```